# Show posts for current taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop

So I have a custom Wordpress `wp_query` loop within `taxonomy.php` that is showing all custom post type posts, sorted by a custom meta field (`start_date`). Within this template I have links to each taxonomy child that uses the same page template. **This does not work** using the loop code I have, shown below.

I want this loop to be able to detect the current taxonomy and show posts in that taxonomy only. So for example my setup is as follows:

- Themes (Taxonomy name)
- Poetry
- Politics
- Environment
- etc.

So when you visit `http://example.com/themes` I want to show all posts within this taxonomy but when you visit `http://example.com/themes/poetry` for example, I want to show only show Poetry posts.

**Here's my loop:**

```
$today = date('Ymd');

$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

$args = array (
  'post_type' => 'whatson',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'start_date',
        'compare' => '>=',
        'value' => $today,
    )
  ),
  'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $term->name,
            'field'    => $term->slug
        ),
    ),
  'meta_key' => 'start_date',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'order' => 'ASC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );


if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
```

This code breaks the template and when I print the query to see what is returned I get the following result:

```
Array ( 

[post_type] => whatson 

[meta_query] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => start_date [compare] => >= [value] => 20170213 ) ) 

[tax_query] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [taxonomy] => Politics [field] => politics ) ) 

[meta_key] => start_date 

[orderby] => meta_value 

[order] => ASC 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the above query, it seems that you have passed wrong parameters in tax_query of your query.

It should be as follows:

```
'tax_query' => array(
       array(
           'taxonomy' => 'Themes', //Your custom taxonomy slug
           'field'    => 'slug', // this should be field name, not field value
           'terms'                => array('environment'),
           'include_children' => true,      
               'operator' => 'IN'  
       ),
   ),
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That's it, I think its working correctly. Thanks! I'm a first timer when it comes to taxonomies so I'm learning all the time at the mo.